# Where to put methods used by multiple classes?

Tags: oop

To show an example what is this question about:

I have currently a dilemma in PHP project I'm working on. I have in mind a method that will be used by multiple classes (UIs in this case - MVC model), but I'm not sure how to represent such methods in OO design. The first thing that came into my mind was to create a class with static functions that I'd call whenever I need them. However I'm not sure if it's the right thing to do.

To be more precise, I want to work, for example, with time. So I'll need several methods that handle time. I was thinking about creating a Time class where I'd be functions that check whether the time is in correct format etc.

Some might say that I shouldn't use class for this at all, since in PHP I can still use procedural code. But I'm more interested in answer that would enlighten me how to approach such situations in OOP / OOD.

So the actual questions are: How to represent such methods? Is static function approach good enough or should I reconsider anything else?

Comment: You should only use an inheritance approach if the classes are related by an IS_A relationship. Otherwise use a module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend creating a normal class the contains this behavior, and then let that class implement an interface extracted from the class' members.

Whenever you need to call those methods, you inject the **interface** (not the concrete class) into the consumer. This lets you vary the two independently of each other.

This may sound like more work, but is simply the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) design pattern applied.

This will also make it much easier to unit test the code, because the code is more loosely coupled.

---

Here's an example in C#.

Interface:

```
public interface ITimeMachine
{
    IStopwatch CreateStopwatch();

    DateTimeOffset GetNow();
}
```

Production implementation:

```
public class RealTimeMachine : ITimeMachine
{
    #region ITimeMachine Members

    public IStopwatch CreateStopwatch()
    {
        return new StopwatchAdapter();
    }

    public DateTimeOffset GetNow()
    {
        return DateTimeOffset.Now;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and here's a consumer of the interface:

```
public abstract class PerformanceRecordingSession : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IStopwatch watch;

    protected PerformanceRecordingSession(ITimeMachine timeMachine)
    {
        if (timeMachine == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("timeMachine");
        }        

        this.watch = timeMachine.CreateStopwatch();
        this.watch.Start();
    }

    public abstract void Record(long elapsedTicks);

    public virtual void StopRecording()
    {
        this.watch.Stop();
        this.Record(this.watch.ElapsedTicks);
    }
}
```

Comment: This means I should create class for handling custom functions + class for each of these functions and then simply call just execute()? So, for example, function "timeToString" would become a separate class with just execute() function, implementing interface. And I'd call it through new CustomFunction( new TimeToString ); ... $custom_function->execute() ? Is this how Strategy pattern works or do I misunderstand the concept? Isn't it a bit of overkill to create basically class for every single function?

Comment: You don't have to create a class for each function. You can bundle related operations in a single class. That's what encapsulation and cehesion is all about, after all. Those operations can all be defined on the same interface, thus giving you the ability to pass around a single cohesive set of operations in a bundle.

Comment: Could you, please, edit your post with a short example (in any language)? As I still fail to understand how exactly to do this. Should I simply create a class with multiple functions, implement an interface extracted from members and then inject this interface where ever I need it and call all those functions through it? I think what confuses me is that you mentioned Strategy pattern and I'm trying to implement the solutions exactly by it. I also don't understand why would I have an interface that is implemented by just one class. Just to prevent tight couplings by calling concrete class?

Answer (score 1):

Although you say you want a structure for arbitrary, unrelated functions, you have given an example of a Time class, which has many related functions. So from an OO point of view you would create a Time class and have a static function `getCurrentTime()`, for example, which returns an instance of this class. Or you could define that the constuctors default behaviour is to return the current time, whichever you like more. Or both.

```
class DateTime {

    public static function getNow() {
        return new self();
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->setDateTime('now');
    }

    public function setDateTime($value) {
        #...
    }

}
```

But apart from that, there is already a [builtin DateTime class in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use a class as a namespace.  So yes, have a static class.

```
class Time {
    public static function getCurrentTime() {
        return time() + 42;
    }
}
```

Comment: Static class = tight coupling

Comment: @Seemann, I prefer simple to "correct" and "proper" solutions (yes, I'm somewhat of a hypocrite at times...).  If I need to make a "normal" class later, I can easily refactor the code to do that.  Otherwise, it's wasted time, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do PHP, but from an OO point of view, placing these sorts of utility methods as static methods is fine. If they are completely reusable in nature, consider placing them in a utils class.

Comment: Static class = tight coupling

Comment: Not that I don't appreciate IoC/dep inj, but in this instance, where a method deals with something as straightforward and non-extendable as time, creating another level of indirection seems to me to be overengineering.

Comment: Time is neither straight-forward nor non-extendable. In unit testing it is often very important that you can simulate that the 'current' time has many different values within miliseconds of each other.